# How do I wipe my USB properly?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, usb-drive, secure-erase

USB - 16GB - Had viruses

Nwiped USB...didn't complete.

Used DoD Short method.

Didn't complete

Now I can only read 16MiB of USB

```
fdisk -l /dev/sdb

Disk /dev/sdb: 16 MB, 16777216 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2 cylinders, total 32768 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
```

Disks Readout:
[image]

Each time I try to mount it this happens:
[image]

How do I wipe this usb properly and get back all 16GB?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would try:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb && sync
sudo mkfs.vfat -I -n "Xplode" /dev/sdb
mkdir ~/usb
sudo mount /dev/sdb ~/usb/
```

If that doesn't work, then you might have a hardware issue with it, meaning that the drive (or controller in the drive) itself is bad.  In that case, go to [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002U1ZBG0) and order one for $6.

Comment: OK tried that. This is what I am getting now.

Comment: electro@electro-HP:~$ sudo fdisk -l


Disk /dev/sdb: 781 MB, 781176832 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 94 cylinders, total 1525736 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Comment: Repeat the process and tell me what you get.  If it comes up different (presumably larger) then you may have to repeat the process until you get to 16ishGB.  Otherwise, order a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb && sync
```

Make sure your USB-Stick is `/dev/sdb`.